# scope of instantiated class / was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++

I'm a new person to C++, but i have learned a little Java and I/m working with SDL for the first time at the same time but my problem is I'm trying to create an object (paddle) p1 and p2.

this

```
#ifndef PONG_H_
#define PONG_H_
#undef main
#include <SDL/SDL.h>
#include <SDL/SDL_image.h>
#include <SDL/SDL_ttf.h>



class paddle{
private:
    int y;
    int yv;
    int x;
public:

    paddle(){
    y = 0;
    yv = 0;
    x = 0;
    }

    paddle(int ex, int why, int vel){
        y = why;
        yv = vel;
        x = ex;
        }

    void setY(int ycoord) {y = ycoord;}
    void setV(int velocity){ yv = velocity;}
    void setX(int xcoord) {x = xcoord;}
    int getX() {return x;}
    int getY() {return y;}
    int update(){y += yv; return y;}




};


class Pong { //pong class where everythin gets its name and a purpose.

private:

    SDL_Surface * Paddle;
    SDL_Surface * Ball; //SDL_Surface pointer for Ball
    SDL_Surface * screen;   //SDL_Surface  pointer to backbuffer

public:
    int Running;
    Pong(); //eh..

    int OnExecute(); //another function returning a value.
    int w; //width of screen
    int h; //height of screen
    bool OnInit();
    void OnEvent(SDL_Event* Event);
    void OnLoop();
    void OnRender();
    void OnCleanup();


    void redraw( int x, int y, SDL_Surface* source, SDL_Surface* destination ) { //Make a temporary rectangle to hold the offsets
    SDL_Rect offset; //Give the offsets to the rectangle
    offset.x = x; offset.y = y;
    SDL_BlitSurface( source, NULL, destination, &offset );//Blit the surface
    offset.x =0; offset.y=0; //resets the offsets sicne they apaprently dont reset per use.
    };

};


#endif /* PONG_H_ */
```

is my header file, it contains the main functions of pong class also but I omitted those to make things less convoluted. Let me know if those are needed for a good answer.

and i declare the objects here...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SDL/SDL.h>

#include "Pong.h"
paddle p1;
paddle p2;

Pong::Pong(){
h = 768;
w = 1024;
screen = NULL;
Paddle = NULL;
Ball = NULL;

Running = true;
atexit(SDL_Quit);

}

int Pong::OnExecute() {
    if(OnInit() == false)
        return-1;
    SDL_Event Event;
    while(Running) {
        while(SDL_PollEvent(&Event)) {
            OnEvent(&Event);
        }

        OnLoop();
        OnRender();
    }
    OnCleanup();
return 0;
}

int main( int argc, char* args[]) {
    Pong theApp;
    return theApp.OnExecute();
}
```

but what sort of makes it difficult is i use it in...here:

```
#include "Pong.h"
void Pong::OnEvent(SDL_Event* Event) {
    if(Event->type == SDL_QUIT)
        Running = false;
    switch(Event->type)
    {

        case SDL_KEYDOWN: //look for key holds
            switch(Event->key.keysym.sym) //check key values and changes coords respectiely
            {
            default:
                break;
            case SDLK_UP:
                p2.setV(-2);
                break;

            case SDLK_DOWN:
                p2.setV(2);
                break;

            case SDLK_w:
                p1.setV(-2);
                break;

            case SDLK_s:
                p1.setV(2);
                break;

            case SDLK_ESCAPE:
            Running = false;
                break;
            }
            break;
        case SDL_KEYUP:
            switch(Event->key.keysym.sym)
            {
            default:
                break;
                case SDLK_UP:
                    p2.setV(0);
                    break;

                case SDLK_DOWN:
                    p2.setV(0);
                    break;

                case SDLK_w:
                    p1.setV(0);
                    break;

                case SDLK_s:
                    p1.setV(0);
                    break;
            }
            break;
        break;//break of Key holding event check
    }
}
```

Its hard for me to ask the question because I don't know where to begin. I tried many different weird things and I'm just lost now. If you need any more info I'll be happy to provide.

```
void Pong::OnLoop(){

    if(p1.getY()<=0){
        p1.setV(0);
        p1.setY(0);
    }
    if(p2.getY()<=0){
        p2.setV(0);
        p2.setY(0);
    }
    if(p1.getY()>=h - Paddle->h){
        p1.setV(0);
            p1.setY(h - Paddle->h);
        }
    if(p2.getY()>=h - Paddle->h){
        p2.setV(0);
            p2.setY(h - Paddle->h);
        }
}
```

..\src\Pong_OnLoop.cpp:11:5: error: 'p1' was not declared in this scope

..\src\Pong_OnLoop.cpp:15:5: error: 'p2' was not declared in this scope

..\src\Pong_OnLoop.cpp:19:5: error: 'p1' was not declared in this scope

..\src\Pong_OnLoop.cpp:23:5: error: 'p2' was not declared in this scope

Comment: What is the issue here? I would though use Paddle* p1 / Paddle* p2 instead, and allocate them with new Paddle() during execution. Aside from that I don't see any obvious errors as of now, and since you have no said what your issue is, its hard to tell.

Comment: That is a lot of code for no question. Could you cut it down to an example that illustrates your problem, and also tell us what the problem is?

Comment: The most important part of a question is the question itself. What is the issue that you are facing? What error are you getting from the compiler (exact error and line)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you haven't provided a clear question, it's difficult to provide the right answer, but my guess is that you can't access p1 and p2 in the OnEvent-/OnLoop-Method.

Is it absolutely necessary to let the two paddle-objects live in the global namespace? Because in this scenario I think it would be best to have 2 paddle-members as part of the Pong class, also I would use initialization lists like so:

```
class Pong {
private:

    SDL_Surface * Paddle;
    SDL_Surface * Ball; //SDL_Surface pointer for Ball
    SDL_Surface * screen;   //SDL_Surface  pointer to backbuffer

    paddle p1;
    paddle p2;

public:
    Pong() :
        h(768),
        w(1024),
        screen(NULL),
        Paddle(NULL),
        Ball(NULL),
        Running(true),
        p1(10, 384, 0),
        p2(1014, 384, 0) {
        atexit(SDL_Quit);
    };

    // ...
};
```

You might not even need all initializers depending on the optimization settings and the default memory initialization but that's not the point. This way you should have access to p1 and p2 in all of Pongs own methods. Bo Perssons answer may work as well, but I think this is a more object- and thus C++-oriented approach.

On a side note: You said that the header file contains some more methods - seeing that your constructor is implemented in the cpp-file and the redraw-Method in the header-file you might want to learn a bit more about inlining. It won't be much of an issue in this example but it's usually best practice to move the more complex methods to the translation units (cpp-files), especially when creating libraries.

Comment: just curious but why would you put paddle p1 and p2 in private:?

Comment: also it seems like you consolidated my Pong.h and Pong.cpp into Pong.h directly.I'm still trying to figure out how that is any different than mien except that you put the two files into one

Comment: Well it's not bad by default to make it public, but a class is private by default out of a reason. The more you make public, the harder it gets to maintain the code once other modules start using the Pong-Class. If this is a small project and that's all there is to it, making it public won't hurt though. The code you provided should work with private members since you are only accessing the paddles from within the Pong-class.

Comment: The "consolidation" is what I referred to as inlining. That was not strictly necessary, but when the constructor is basically only initializing class members it might as well be implemented in the header file. You can leave it in the cpp-file though if you want, shouldn't make a difference. I'm only talking about the constructor, complex methods should better be left in the cpp-file, as you did with OnEvent / OnLoop.

Comment: ooooh, I think some of this is starting to make sense. for soem reason i thought that I couldnt put the paddle members in the pong class since they were created in... see I don't even know my own logic for not trying that but it makes so much sense now. and honestly if i wanted to could i combine my Pong .h and .cpp into a Pong.cpp and #include that in my other cpps? in the SDL tutorials i found it kind of pointless to separate their contents like that. I still don't understand the full nature of .h files.

Comment: unfortunately the reason i got these errors in the first place was because I was trying to convert my code from being all variables into being object based. i had like int x1 int x2 int y1 int y2 ...etc it makes more sense for me to use p1.getX and p2.getX. sadly now the program wont run correctly :c but your fix did fix my errors i was having with it!

Comment: It's best to get a good book or tutorial on this topic, especially when you're used to Java, but basically the header file should provide the _declaration_ and the cpp-file should provide the _definition_. So the header says what it CAN DO, and the CPP-files explain HOW it does it. If another class implemented in another cpp-file needs to use the class Pong, it doesn't need to know HOW it's implemented, it just needs to know what methods are available for calling.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the paddles visible in more than the file they are defined in, you have to add a declaration to the header file

```
extern paddle p1;
extern paddle p2;
```

so the other .cpp files will know that they exist.

Comment: unfortunately when i do that it says the variable p1 and p2 are now unused. and the other error persists

Comment: Ok, like *what* other errors? :-) You could add those to the question.